# Why is my function block not online in Twincat simulation mode?

Tags: twincat

I have created a function block within the POU location and when i try and run the project as a simulation my function block is not online, when adding it to my "main" i get the error "Functionblock  must be instantiated to be accessed. Any help on how to solve this please.

im expecting in simulation mode to be able to turn on and off contacts withing my function block ladder logic to ensure it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your function block as a variable in the declaration area of main.

[image]

Comment: This is true, but understanding why is important. A function block is (or at least can be) reusable. If you could use a function block without declaring it, it would mean there would be a single, global instance. Imagine if you had to code each TON function block in your application individually... Requiring each instance to be declared explicitly is what allows multiple instances (each with its own INPUT/OUTPUT/VAR, etc.). So there are really, really strong reasons it is this way.